# Change iFrame dimensions of all iFrames on Websites

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, customization

I've embedded several youtube videos in my blog. Is it possible to use JS to change the dimensions of ALL embedded players on the blog to ensure that every video has the exact same formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I assume these are iframes?

```
var frame = $("iframe");
frame.css("height", "500");
frame.css("width", "500");
```

You can change the second value to anything in pixels.

Better would be to use CSS for this:

```
iframe {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}
```

If those are not iframes change the iframe tag to any other tag